# how to use a class in multiple panels

Tags: java, jbutton, redundancy

i'm making a tank game. to avoid redundancy to make my buttons in the menupanel i wrote a class button:

```
package menu;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Button extends JButton{

    public JButton button;
    public ImageIcon buttonImage;

    public int x, width, height;

    public String backgroundPath;
    public int y;



    public Button(String backgroundPath,int x, int y, MenuPanel menuPanel)

    {
        super();
        this.backgroundPath = backgroundPath;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        buttonImage = new 
            ImageIcon(PlayPanel.class.getResource(backgroundPath));
        this.setIcon(buttonImage);
        this.setBounds(x, y, buttonImage.getIconWidth(), 
            buttonImage.getIconHeight());
        this.addActionListener(menuPanel);   
    }
}
```

in the constructor of the method i have `MenuPanel menupanel`but i want to be able to use this code is multiple panels like the QuitPanel, HighScorePanel, ...etc.

i don't know which parameter i have to use for this so i'm stuck.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Create the object of Button in each panel and add it in the panel in which you want.

Comment: they don't extend `MenuPanel`,  they extend `JPanel` but they all come together in the `MenuPanel` to appear on screen, thanks ;)

Comment: Can you please post the structure of these classes to see how these all panels look like?

Comment: i'm making a class IPanel atm so i can extend that class to all my panels!

Comment: @akhil_mittal my IPanel rn looks like:

[https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=1D73EE388A388E7B!213&app=Word&wdnd=1&wdNewAndOpenCt=1431076798916&wdPreviousCorrelation=59fdae29%2Dd6d4%2D425f%2D89eb%2Dc39401ba4102]

when i want to extend this in (for example my HTPPanel) i get this:
[https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=1D73EE388A388E7B!217&app=Word&wdnd=1&wdNewAndOpenCt=1431076941365&wdPreviousCorrelation=79973e2a%2D5357%2D42c5%2Dbee4%2D732ef523583f]

but i get the error "Implicit super constructor IPanel() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"

Comment: @akhil_mittal  i fixed the parameter problem, but i still want to use this IPanel class because my panels do have a lot of properties in common. how do i have to fix the "Implicit super constructor IPanel() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor"-error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `MenuPanel menuPanel` parameter to `ActionListener` listener, since the only reason for it is to make it easier to attach an `ActionListener` to it, the button doesn't need to know about `MenuPanel`

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an interface `IPanel` and make your `QuitPanel`, `HighScorePanel`, and `MenuPanel` implement that interface. I believe each of these panels must be implementing some common methods whose declarations can be moved to `IPanel` interface. Then you can pass `IPanel` as an argument in constructor rather than `MenuPanel`.

Comment: Like ActionListener for example ;)

Comment: :) Right!! You got the point. I was more interested in providing hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

If MenuPanel is an instance of JPanel then you could change your code like this...

```
public Button(String backgroundPath,int x, int y, JPanel pane);
```

Comment: Except JPanel doesn't implement ActionListener